# How do create a Generic Object using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-4.5

First let me say, that what I want to do is get the value of a property in a generic class that may be overriden by class that inherits from it. Think of it in the base class as a default value, that the inheritor of the class can override to set their own Default value.

I have tried to use reflection directly on the type, using the System.Reflection.FieldInfo.GetValue but this does not work for classes with generic types. So I think that I need to instantiate the class to be able to see what the value is.

The "types" I have I retrieved by reading the Dlls in the bin and using Reflection to find the types that inherit from my interface.

I am using .NET 4.5

here is documentation that seems like it explains exactly what I need to do
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx

In this documentation the only difference I can see is how we got our types, I looked in the bin for types and they simply called typeof(), Since types are so complex it seems this may be a likely mis-match but I cannot see what is missing(if anything)

```
foreach (var item in types)
{
    var ts = item.GetField("DefaultTimeToExpire");
    Type[] typeArguments = item.GetGenericArguments();
    if (ts != null)
    {
        var t = item.MakeGenericType(typeArguments);
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        var timespan = obj.DefaultTimeToExpire;
        subscriberInfos.Add(new Tuple<string, Type, TimeSpan>(item.Name, item, timespan));
    }
}
```

I am calling GetField to look for Items that have a field "DefaultTimeToExpire" so far this part works well to find the type I need.
Next I call GetGenericArguments which returns an expected array of the type Arguments. 
then I call MakeGenericType
and finally Create instance wich gives me the error message

"Cannot create an instance of BusinessLogic.TestSubscriberXXX`1[Message] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true."

This looks like exactly what I am supposed to do.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that your `typeArguments` doesn't have enough types in it to set all of the generic's type parameters?

Comment: Strange error, hard to guess how you ended up with an open type.  The shortcut is to just use Activator.CreateInstance(item.GetType()).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to instantiate a generic type, you need to know the actual values (types) that should be substituted for its type parameters. The `GetGenericArguments()` method, being a form of reflection, only gives you the type *arguments*, not their actual values. The values are up to you... that is the entire point of generics.

If `item` is a type like `List<T>` then `item.GetGenericArguments()` will return an array containing a fake "type" representing the type parameter `T` (with its `IsGenericParameter` property set to true). Therefore,  passing that parameter type back into `item.MakeGenericType()` will simply create another open generic type equivalent to the original. To close the generic type so that it can be instantiated you need to provide an actual (non-parameter) type argument, such as `int`.

For example, `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int))` will return `typeof(List<int>)`, while  `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(List<>).GetGenericArguments())` will simply return `typeof(List<>)` again. This is what is happening in your code.

I'm sorry if that is a bit opaque, I don't know how else to explain it. The bottom line is that a type like `List<T>` is only useful if you have a type you want to substitute in place of `T`.

Comment: Item is a type like List<User> when I call GetGenericArguments() and I inspect what gets returned, it returns a type that I am expecting. The "User". One thing that is suspicious is the FullName is null, although it does have the Assembly fully qualified name

Comment: FullName being null is odd... I've never seen that before. If it's returning User (and User is an actual type, not a type parameter) then you already have a closed generic type. You should then be able to simply do `Activator.CreateInstance(item)`'.

Comment: Ok I have no idea why I am not able to create the correct generic type to allow the CreateInstance to work but I have solved my problem. This code is actually inside a generic class that implements the Type I am trying to create as my generic type. So I can just write: ` var typeArg = typeof(T); var t = item.MakeGenericType(typeArg); ISubscriber<T> subscriber = (ISubscriber<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(t); var timespan = subscriber.DefaultTimeToExpire; subscriberInfos.Add(new Tuple<string, Type, TimeSpan>(item.Name, item, timespan)); `